# Loop through distinct values in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on a report from a data set that contains several columns, one of which is a Customer Name. Each row of data is a unique invoice, but the customer names are repeated many times. My client would like for the customer names to appear in the title of the report: "Customer A, Customer B, Customer C Report."

Right now, I'm using `=Fields!csg_name.Value & " Report"` as the constant on the report, but it only returns the value for one of the customer names. How do I get it to do concatenate all of the distinct names?  Do I use a `SELECT DISTINCT` as part of the query, or can I do this as part of the report?

I should mention that I'm working with SQL Server 2000, and designing in VS 2003, .NET 1.1 (yes, we need to upgrade... everything.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to display values in a textbox outside of any data region, you could add a Hidden, ReadOnly parameter(Customer_name) to the report bound to your data set.  You can then use =join(parameters!Customer_name.Value, ",") & " Report".

OR

You can create a separate dataset returning comma separated list of distinct customer names.

Comment: Thanks, @AgentSQL. I thought adding a separate dataset would be a good solution, but I can only find options to add a new Data _Source_. Am I right that that's not the same thing?

Comment: No, it is not same. You will find Datasets folder in Report Data explorer. And you can right click it and add new dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LookUpSet`for your field `=Fields!csg_name.Value` 
Heres the documentation for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is available in 2000. I think it was introduced in 2008 R2.